# pseudocode - zellers congruence - python

Tags: python, date, pseudocode

I am taking my first class in programming (python). My assignment is to write pseudocode and later a python program that will calculate the day of the week using dd/mm/yyyy as inputs. I am using [Zeller's congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) to calculate the day of week. This is my first attempt as pseudocode - I am hoping to get some feedback. I am not sure if i am on the right track. Is my logic clear? Will a beginner be able to translate this into python? Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Program Calculate the Day
Purpose of the program: this program inputs a date and calculates the day of the week on which it occurred.
Date: 6/4/14

# Prompt a user to type his/her birthdate as three different values

print "In what month were you born?"
Input mm

print "on what day of the month?"
Input dd

print "In what year were you born?"
Input yyyy

# adjusts inputs to account for algorithm if birthdate occurs on Jan or Feb

if input mm = 1 or mm = 2:

mm = mm + 12 

and

yyyy = yyyy - 1

# stores inputs as variables for use in zellers congruence

store mm as m
store dd as q
store yyyy as y

# Calculate the day of the week and store it in a variable named dow

dow = ( ( q + ( (m + 1) * 26 // 10 )+ Y +( Y // 4 )+ 6 * (Y // 100 )+ (Y // 400 )) % 7 )

Output "you were born on a Day" dow

# Notice that there is no space between the word “Day” and the number; this helps it look like one of those “number for days” cultures
```

Comment: looks good. what's your question exactly?

Comment: If the user enters valid data, then it will more or less work if you've transcribed Zeller's Congruence correctly — I've not checked that.  Your output should reflect the input as well as the answer, so you can tell what the computer thinks you entered.  You might want to think about users entering a month number such as 0, -1, 13, etc; you should probably think about them entering days such as -1, 0, 32, (31 when month is 11, 4, 6, or 9; and 29 or 30 when month is 2).  Maybe you should limit the range of years, too.

Comment: Thank you both so much! I was worried about that as well... What is a good way to limit the input range in pseudocode? I am a complete beginner - I am also worried about the section where i modify the mm and yyyy inputs. Is it even possible to modify them and store them as m and y variables in python?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started learning python and have the solution for your problem. Please let me know if you like it or have any questions

```
#importing functions
import time 
import sys
import datetime
import math 
start=time.perf_counter()#starting timer
hi=str(input('enter date in mm/dd/yyyy'))#asking for input
try:
    date= datetime.datetime.strptime(hi,'%m/%d/%Y').date()#checking for format
    d2=str(date.year)
    l3=d2[:2] #breaking up string 
    l4=d2[2:]
    C=int(l3)
    D=int(l4)
    K=date.day
    M=date.month
if M==1:# making zellers month system 
    D=D-1
    M=11
elif M==2:
    D=D-1
    M=12
else:
    M=M-2
#breaking up the equation.The equation is  f = k + [(13*m-1)/5] + D + [D/4] + 
[C/4] - 2*C
f=13*M
g=f-1
a=g/5
a=math.floor(a) #cutting off the decimals
z=a+K
b=D/4
b=math.floor(b)
c=C/4
c=math.floor(c)
d=2*C
f1=(z+b+c+D)
d1=f1-d   
l=d1 % 7 # getting remainder
l=math.floor(l)#cutting off decimals 
if (l==1):#using remainder to find day of week
    print('The day is Mon')
elif (l==2):
    print('The day is Tue')
elif (l==3):
    print('The day is Wed')
elif (l==4):
    print('The day is Thu')
elif (l==5):
    print('The day is Fri')
elif (l==6):
    print('The day is Sat')
elif (l==7 or 0):
    print('The day is Sun')
#printing the day

except Exception:
        print('Please enter date in correct format')#error statement 
else:
    #calculating final time
    end=time.perf_counter()
    a5=end-start
    message='The time taken is %s seconds'
    print(message % a5)#displaying time
```